# how to make android WebView indistinguishable with desktop firefox?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i want show a captcha in my webView, this captcha is loaded by java script code that run in the WebView, every thing is ok and the captcha image is loaded fine, but the captcha image is very different from the one that is loaded in opera browser(android) or firefox(desktop) while the script that load the captcha is same in all of them(webView, Opear, firefox).
i cant solve this. i tried to change WebView UserAgent but did not help.
i know that the server that the script is communicating with distinguishes these browsers but i can not find how.

is there any thing that can i do in webView to make it indistinguishable with android opera browser or desktop firefox??

```
<html>
        <center>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Le19M0SAAAAANqE7Uzwb2zXFTKjAi0OlWjhjBfz"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Le19M0SAAAAANqE7Uzwb2zXFTKjAi0OlWjhjBfz" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>         
                <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit SMS" class="submit" title="Send Free SMS" style="margin: 0 auto; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #505050; padding: 5px;" />

            </center>
</html>
```